# How to write the summation along an axis of a matrix?

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to write an example for an equation involving summing a matrix across its columns.

The example has to show the matrix values, so it would ideally be in the form:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_m \\
\end{bmatrix}
= $ op $
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1,1}&\dots&b_{1,n}\\ \vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\ b_{m,1}&\dots&b_{m,n}
\end{bmatrix}
$

Where: $a_t = \sum_{i=1}^n b_{t,i}$

What should $op$ be replaced with here to illustrate the summing across columns?

Comment: Transpose the matrix at the right and multiply it (to the right) with column vector [1,1,1,..,1]. Will that do?

Comment: @amitava That seems to be best way I can find. If you wanna put this as the answer I'll mark it right.

Comment: Oh yes. Getting some points is somehow motivating, :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_m \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1,1}&\dots&b_{1,n}\\ \vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\ b_{m,1}&\dots&b_{m,n}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1_1 \\ \vdots \\ 1_m
\end{bmatrix}
$

$A_m=B_{m,n} \times J_m$

($J$ typically being used when referring to a [matrix of ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_of_ones))